# Proxy settings for CentOS 8 not working

Tags: centos, proxy, dnf, http-proxy

I've tried installing a CentOS 8 server behind a corporate proxy but I can't seem to figure out why it won't let me do any connection commands.

```
vi /etc/profile.d/proxy.sh
# proxy    settings
MB_PROXY_URL="http://username:password@proxy.domain.ltd:3128/"

http_proxy=$MB_PROXY_URL
https_proxy=$MB_PROXY_URL
ftp_proxy=$MB_PROXY_URL
no_proxy="127.0.0.1,localhost,domain.ltd,192.168.0.*"

HTTP_PROXY=$MB_PROXY_URL
HTTPS_PROXY=$MB_PROXY_URL
FTP_PROXY=$MB_PROXY_URL
NO_PROXY="127.0.0.1,localhost,domain.ltd,192.168.0.*"

export http_proxy https_proxy ftp_proxy no_proxy HTTP_PROXY HTTPS_PROXY FTP_PROXY NO_PROXY

# then run
source /etc/profile.d/proxy.sh
```

---

```
vi /etc/dnf/dnf.conf
# proxy settings
proxy=http://proxy.domain.ltd:3128/
proxy_username=username
proxy_password=password
```

---

```
vi /etc/wgetrc
# proxy settings
http_proxy    = http://username:password@proxy.domain.ltd:3128/
https_proxy    = http://username:password@proxy.domain.ltd:3128/
ftp_proxy    = http://username:password@proxy.domain.ltd:3128/
no_proxy    = "127.0.0.1,localhost,domain.ltd,192.168.0.*"
```

---

I have the exact settings on a CentOS 7 server (except `yum` instead of `dnf`) and I am able to connect to do updates or installs.

The error message I receive when running: `yum -y update kernel` or `yum -y update` or `yum -y upgrade` is:

```
[root@server01 ~]# yum install nano
CentOS-8 - AppStream                                                   106 kB/s | 2.1 kB     00:00    
Failed to download metadata for repo 'AppStream'
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'AppStream'
```

I have searched around for a solution to proxies, and to the `AppStream` but nothing seems to work.

When I run the commands verbose, I get the `HTTP 407` error but I cant seem to find any other areas to add a proxy.

Some things I have tried are:

- changing the repo from `mirror` to `base`
- changing the repo from `http` to `https`
- disabling the SELINUX
- stopping the firewall

There doesn't seem to be as much documentation for CentOS 8 but hopefully someone can help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the dnf has changed the way it deals with proxies. If you’re using a basic proxy authentication then you need to specify it:

```
vi /etc/dnf/dnf.conf
# proxy settings
proxy=http://proxy.domain.ltd:3128/
proxy_username=username
proxy_password=password
proxy_auth_method=basic
```

Answer (score 0):

This [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/592521/97255) didn't work for me for whatever reason.

I had to use my older CentOS 7 settings plus the `proxy_ user/pass/auth` - one or the other would not work and squid proxy always logged "tcp_denied/407" indicating basic HTTP authentication was required.

## MRE

**Files**:

- `/etc/redhat-release`:

  ```
  Rocky Linux release 8.4 (Green Obsidian)
  ```
- `/etc/squid/squid.conf`:

  ```
  auth_param basic program /usr/lib64/squid/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwd
  ```
- `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf`:

  ```
  [main]
  gpgcheck=1
  installonly_limit=3
  clean_requirements_on_remove=True
  best=True
  skip_if_unavailable=False
  proxy=http://MY_PROXY_USER:MY_PROXY_PASS@MY_PROXY_HOST:MY_PROXY_PORT
  #proxy=http://MY_PROXY_HOST:MY_PROXY_PORT
  proxy_auth_method=basic
  proxy_user=MY_PROXY_USER
  proxy_password=MY_PROXY_PASS
  #sslverify=0
  debuglevel=10
  ```
- `~/.curlrc`:

  ```
  proxy=MY_PROXY_HOST:MY_PROXY_PORT
  proxy-user=MY_PROXY_USER:MY_PROXY_PASS
  ```

**Test**:

```
tail -f /var/log/squid/access.log
```

```
dnf clean all && dnf -vv search --showduplicates librepo-
```

- This works with and without `sslverify=0`
- This works with and without `~/.curlrc` settings
- This only works with all the proxy settings not commented out.

I hope this helps someone.